# Add CSS class to button disabled by Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following button that gets disabled if the user is in the first page:

```
<button :disabled="page==1" v-on:click="page=1;run()" class="page-link" :class="{'disabled' : disabled}">First</button>
```

However i would like to add the class `.disabled` if said button is disabled by Vue. Is it possible to do this through Vue?

Comment: you can also put the same condition directly to the class directive: `:class="{'disabled' : page === 1}"`

Comment: @Serg That worked, could you please create an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the same condition directly to the class directive:

```
 :class="{'disabled' : page === 1}"
```

Comment: It's an older answer, but thank you! This helped me.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing disabled to false in the onclick, something like this: `v-on:click="page=1;run();!disabled"` or `v-on:click="page=1;run();disabled=false"`.

Comment: I dont have a disabled variable or prop, only the bind on the disabled attribute in the html to be disabled if a condition is met `:disabled="page==1"`